# What is "Self-Hosting"?

Tags: term

Up to now I thought self-hosting was for example, running its own nextcloud server on a virtual private server.

I read the wikipedia article, and it talks about something different:

> Self-hosting is the use of a computer program as part of the toolchain or operating system that produces new versions of that same program—for example, a compiler that can compile its own source code.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting

If "Running its own nextcloud server on a virtual private server" is not self-hosting.

How to call "Running its own nextcloud server on a virtual private server"?

On stackoverflow it's definied like this:

> Operating independently of a hosting infrastructure.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-hosting

Comment: The tag information on [so] says: "Self-hosting refers to a program or service which does not require a hosting environment. This term is often used to describe WCF web services that do not require IIS as their web host - a self-hosted WCF service establishes its own HTTP endpoints and listeners and is responsible for its own routing, security, and configuration management." But that's what SO has chosen to use the tag for. Our context is different, as TomTom has noted below.

Comment: @MichaelHampton where did you see the long explanation. If I look at the tag "self-hosting" I only see the string which I wrote into my question. ..... Ah, now I see, you can click on "learn more". I am sorry I only read "Operating independently of a hosting infrastructure.".

Answer (score 4):

First you try to simplify the world too much. Self-Hosting has different meanings in different contexts, so ignoring the context is not good. Another example of self-hosting, i.e. (and running along the not using hosting infrastructure) is self hosting a web application in another application because it is inot "the web application that matters". Example? I have systems here that do X and expose a REST based web API to control them. The api is self-hosted by the applications, not using IIS or Apache.

So, the general tenor of your question is wrong - you try to fold various contexts into one term, that generally does not work. I.e. your wikipedia article is a general programming principle for compiler development. The moment a compiler can compile itself is self hosting. But that has NOTHING to do with any relevance of web hosting at all. Different context.

> How to call "Running its own nextcloud server on a virtual private server"?

Hosting. What different is it from any other hosting? Just because you use a VPS? No, not relevant at all in this context.

Answer (score -2):

Self-Hosting a website or public and private web services mean that a person is capable of configuring a regular computer into a webserver over either a dynamic IP address through port forwarding or static IP address which doesn't need port forwarding. For example, i self-host my website on an Acer laptop with windows 10 through a DNS software call NOIP and port forwarding through ISP router.